# FileInfo not working in php 5.3.3

Tags: php, fileinfo

I'm making a simple call to finfo_open() and I get:

"Call to undefined function finfo_open()"

Isn't FileInfo packaged with php 5.3.3 (Unix). Do I need to turn it on in php.ini?

Thanks

Comment: not sure but, can you show the lines of code where u are using it?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar in live server in WordPress maybe anyone can help me...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141795/enabled-fileinfo-but-still-getting-an-error-wordpress-plugin-requiement

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could get it enabled but you're missing some constants. These are the values from my system:

```
FILEINFO_NONE = 0
FILEINFO_SYMLINK = 2
FILEINFO_MIME = 1040
FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE = 16
FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING = 1024
FILEINFO_DEVICES = 8
FILEINFO_CONTINUE = 32
FILEINFO_PRESERVE_ATIME = 128
FILEINFO_RAW = 256
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: I don't know where these constants ought to be, but adding them to php.ini did the trick for me.

Comment: @user508402: How does adding constants in the php.ini work? With the `auto_prepend_file`  directive?

Answer (score 0):

Depends really, the php on your server might have been compiled without it for some reason.

create a new .php file and put the infamous `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and check to see if that extension is compiled in.

Comment: Looks like "SplFileInfo" is enabled (not sure if thats the same thing though). Under "Configure Command" it says: '--disable-fileinfo'.

Comment: well, it's disabled :) Nothing to do about it in that particular server

Comment: @Pardoner: No, that's a different thing. SplFileObject and SplFileInfo have nothing to do with it. But the --disable switch pertains to the `finfo` extension. You could still install it as separate module, if you find/compile it. http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo

Comment: I "pecl install fileinfo", which was successful. But still no change in phpinfo().

Comment: @Pardoner: Check php.ini for extension= load line. And restart Apache. Otherwise it wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: you need to reconfigure, recompile the whole php to make it work

Comment: @mario, Yes I restarted apache. Do I need to put the path to the extension in the php.ini?

Comment: @Pardoner: Preferrably. Linux binaries use an extra `/etc/php5/*/conf.d/`  set of *.ini files. Check if it's there.

Comment: Do I need something like this: `mime_magic.magicfile = "/usr/share/file/magic.mime"
extension=fileinfo.so`

Comment: I added the above lines to php.ini and restarted apache. phpinfo() now shows "fileinfo support: enabled" (still says '--disable-fileinfo' under configure command!!??). After calling finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE) i get "finfo_open() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given..."

Comment: @Pardoner: Looks like the constant `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` is not defined. You could cross-check that with `var_dump(get_defined_constants(1));`.

Comment: the `configure command` are the parameters you pass to the configure script. it will NEVER change, unless you reconfigure and recompile php (ie: ./configure <options> ; make).