# Enabled fileinfo but still getting an error WordPress plugin requiement

Tags: php, wordpress, ini

Recently I uploaded my file on live server and facing this error shown below but everything is working good on my local server.

> Fatal error: Class 'finfo' not found in plugins/doc
>   management/view/add_doc.php on line 71 The site is experiencing
>   technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for
>   instructions.

Code

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$filesize = strlen($file);
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){ 
chmod(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/',0777);
$upload = file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/'.$name,$file);
```

What I have tried so far to get rid of this error.

tried to enabled fileinfo via .htaccess file but getting 500 internal server error page is not working after doing that. I tried to add them in the end of the .htaccess file

```
php_value extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

or

```
php_admin_flag extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Solution2: I tried to add `ini_set('extension', 'php_fileinfo.so');`
to enable fileinfo but stil getting the same error after adding it.

solution 3:
I tried to create a php.ini file in the root folder of the public HTML page to override the php.ini file with mine but it still won't work out getting the same error.

my WordPress site is inside a subfolder of the public_html directory. there is html index.html page on the root as a landing page.

I don't know how to check that it is enabled or not. I create info.php file and added phpinfo() function to see the PHP details it is showing but I don't know what finfo is there how to find it. tried to search out but won't work.

I am having Cpanel access tried but not working out. the ways I tried and I am having PHP 5.6 which is greater than PHP 5.3

I checked out phpinfo(); and in configuration, it is showing...

```
--enable-fileinfo=shared'
```

but still, I am getting the same error.

on my localhost when I use phpinfo() it shows that fileinfo is enabled. but on the server phpinfo() is not showing that fileinfo is availabe.

Answer (score 0):

for these reasons only I have stopped using plugins, If u will code from urself, u won't have any issue in any environment.

try to deactivate your plugins one by one and check, which plugin is causing the issue, if it's possible check another plugin with same features, or can make your own (best way).

Some of your plugin requires finfo (fileinfo)- is an optional php extension. You can enable it through CPanel or in php.ini, depending on your hosting.

**If you are using dedicated hosting, u can edit it by yourself; if not, call your hosting provider.**

Comment: call your hosting provider and ask them to edit php.ini in whm panel

Comment: I am having Cpanel access tried but not working out. the ways I tried and I am having PHP 5.6 which is greater than php 5.3

Comment: from cpanel u can't, until it's dedicated hosting, that's why I said call hosting provider they will have the access of whm (if you are using shared web hosting e.g godaddy, hostgator, big rock etc), tell your hosting provider to upgrade php version too.

Comment: We have own server, self-hosting... not using third party hosting.

Comment: try this, go to Select PHP Version from cpanel, and enable extension. chk screen http://manishpushkar.in/content/uploads/2019/07/screencapture.png, restart your hosting.

Comment: yes, I saw that on youtube but it is not showing on my hosting. it just simply update the PHP version and do not give us the option to select extensions.